# Command execution in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, runtime, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I want to execute this command:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.msgshareapp/.AdminReceiver")`

This didn't work, then I tried this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.example.msgshareapp/.AdminReceiver")`

And this does completly nothing, anyway of executing this command?

Answer (score 0):

```
val command = arrayOf("adb", "shell", "dpm", "set-device-owner", "com.example.msgshareapp/.AdminReceiver")
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

Comment: When doing this, my app crashes. These are the errors: https://gyazo.com/9262d2460e627097ad4659dc16f5a8eb

Comment: You have a "permission denied" error for running _adb_. I cannot help you with that problem as I do not program for Android devices. Maybe check out these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682389/programmatically-executing-adb-shell-dpm-command-within-app-yields-cannot-run-pr